# Use Genymotion to access local node server

Tags: android, node.js, server, genymotion

I start a node server, and it show

> Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/"

and I also get my Genynotion virualBox likes

> $ ifconfig vboxnet0
>   vboxnet0: flags=8943 mtu 1500 ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
>   inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255

so I want to access the server from genymotion by url:http://www.192.168.56.1:3000,but it doesn't work, what else should I need to configure?

Comment: Try running your node server at 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I did as you recommended, but it doesn't work , any more suggestion? thx!

Comment: Take off the www in front of your URL.  It should just be http://192.168.56.1:3000

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: thanks,it works now!